# MaskRcnn model does not train from 'last'

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a [maskRcnn](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/) model on melanoma images. I initially only train the network heads followed by the entire network.
However the code trains only the network heads.

```
model.train(dataset_train,dataset_val,
            learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE,
            epochs=30,
            layers='heads')
```

The subsequent code:

```
model.train(dataset_train,dataset_val,
            learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE,
            epochs=30,
            layers='all')
```

Does not train the model nor does it give an error. Execution simply finishes. The entire script can be found [here](https://github.com/dsouzinator/melanoma-MaskRcnn/blob/master/maskrcnn.py)

Comment: what error did you get when you tried to train your model with last parameter.

Comment: @SohaibAnwaar solved the issue. it requires a different epoch number, so if the second snippet needs to run for 30 epochs, it should actually be 60, because it has already run for 30 epochs